# What is the way to add paypal payment without papypal's button in V2

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have the following cenario: On my page are different payment-options. First you choose the method, where by clicking on the paypal-button shout happens nothing. Only if you click then the order-and-pay-button it shout run the behavior of the paypal-button, with opening the paypal-dialog.

[image]

My first idea was to use the standard paypal-button and store it in an hidden field.
By clicking on my-paypal-button I load the paypal-script like this:

```
    var wasLoaded = false;
 function loadScript() {
    if(wasLoaded) return;
    wasLoaded = true;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = function() {

        paypal.Buttons({

                    // Set up the transaction
                    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [{
                                amount: {
                                    value: '88.44'
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    }, ...
                    load it to a hidden div.

    }

    script.src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SD&intent=capture&vault=false&commit=true';

  }
```

by loading it to an hidden div.
By clicking on order-and-pay I make  button.click() to execute the paypal-stuff.
But unfortunately the papypal-stuff is in a iframe, so I do not have access to it.

I could not find any hint in the paypal-specs. They wont always to use there button.
How can I achieve this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below Server-Side API link which will help you achieve Server-side payment integration without PayPal Client's side button.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/

Feel free to let me know if you have any queries, also I am happy to share postman collections to play around with the APIs.

Speak to you soon!

Regards

Goutham AV

Comment: That what I have already seen. If I understand it in the right way, I have always to redirect to the PayPalHttp\HttpResponse->links where the payment-action runs. But I would like to use the same behaviour like the buttons providing.

Comment: any tutorial and example about without paypal buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a button created, i woud just use a PHP generated Link:

**If a user clicks on it, that user will be redirected to a PayPal Page -> buy on paypal -> get redirected to your page.**

For that purpose i'd recommend PayPal PHP Api: [PayPal PHP Api](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)

**Step 1:** To get your libary working, download and install Paypal Api and start with that code:

```
<?php
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
// Used for composer based installation
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use below for direct download installation
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
```

**Step 2:** You need to setup your PayPay ClientID and Secret:

```
// After Step 1
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'AYSq3RDGsmBLJE-otTkBtM-jBRd1TCQwFf9RGfwddNXWz0uFU9ztymylOhRS',     // ClientID
        'EGnHDxD_qRPdaLdZz8iCr8N7_MzF-YHPTkjs6NKYQvQSBngp4PTTVWkPZRbL'      // ClientSecret
    )
);
```

**Step 3:** Use Code to generate a Link for your Button. You can use Code Samples from the Paypal Api Sample Pages [here](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/)

I would recommend you the Code Sample: "PayPal Payments - similar to Express Checkout in Classic APIs"

I know there are maybe better ways to implement paypal buttons on a webpage, but  this worked best for me.